# Can not delete emails in Outlook Express

Tags: windows, windows-xp, outlook-express

I've got over 10000 something e-mails in my sent and some other inboxes which need to be deleted and removed. However, everytime I try and go in and delete them all I can't. I just get an error. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the exact error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not feasible to do, I decided to remove and recreate the inbox file instead.